# PHP: Need to find certain data from a string

Tags: php, regex

> $string = "Response 22: 404 (8345ms), headers: Accept-Ranges=bytes,
>   Cache-Control=no-cache, no-store, private, Connection=close,
>   Content-Encoding=gzip, Content-Language=it-it, Content-Length=1674,
>   Content-Location=index.html.it-it, Content-Type=text/html;
>   charset=utf-8, Date=Wed, 24 Sep 2014 19:01:30 GMT,
>   ETag='eb1-50331586750c0;503ac178f62dd', Last-Modified=Tue, 16 Sep 2014
>   16:35:55 GMT, Server=Apache,
>   Strict-Transport-Security=max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains,
>   TCN=choice, Vary=negotiate,accept,accept-language,Accept-Encoding,
>   X-Frame-Options=SAMEORIGIN, X-UA-Compatible=IE=Edge";

Here I want to grab response number(=> 22), response code(=> 404) and its milli seconds(=> 8345ms).
I think I have to use regex, but I am new to that. Can you please give any suggestions?

Comment: you can always use getallHeaders() to grab and array of headers and then conveniently iterate

Comment: If the format is always the same, just juse a couple of `explode()`. Much easier then trying to write a complicated regex, in my opinion.

Comment: Why you people see regex as a complicated one?

Comment: Thanks Avinash. I didn't mean its complicated ;), but I am very new to regex. Hope I can learn soon. Could you please suggest me some good online tutorials for the same.

Comment: this would help you http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: Thank you all for your response :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Response\s*(\d+):\s*(\d+)\s*\((\S+)?\)
```

Try this.Get the three groups.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/qC9cH4/3

Comment: Hello there, Thanks a lot for the quick response :)

preg_match('Response\s*(\d+):\s*(\d+)\s*\(\S+?\)', $string, $match);

var_dump($match);

Here I am getting the error, can we use preg_match() here?

Comment: its saying "Warning: preg_match(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash".

Comment: @RameshRaja you forget to add delimiters.

Comment: @vks it's better to use this `Response\s*(\d+):\s*(\d+)\s*\(([^()]+)?\)` instead of `Response\s*(\d+):\s*(\d+)\s*\((\S+)?\)`